# How to bind value to property of NSWindow in Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, macos, interface-builder, key-value-observing

I sub-classed `NSWindow` (named `IMWindow`) to make my own properties. Now I want to bind the value of `NSTextField` to one of the property of `IMWindow`. I know it is possible for `NSUserDefaults` controllers or app delegate. But it does not provide option for `NSWindow`.

I would like to see if I can bind the value to arbitrary object.

Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```
@interface IMMainWindow ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *line1Text;
@end
```

It is hard to find any advance material in Interface Builder for OS X. :-/

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa uses the [MVC (Model-View-Controller)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) pattern. You should be binding the text field's value to a controller, not the window itself. Don't subclass `NSWindow` — create an [`NSWindowController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass with a XIB (so the window controller will become File's Owner) and then add your `line1Text` property to the `NSWindowController` subclass and bind the text field to the File's Owner object in the XIB.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [indragie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21873748/1118969). That said, it is possible to do, what you are asking.

First you have to set the Custom Class of your `IMWindow.xib`. To do so, select the window in the left side and click on the blue highlighted icon in the right side and type in your class name:
[image: Xcode interface builder]

When that is done, you have to create a property for your `NSTextField` this is done by selecting the text field and click the middle icon in the top (the one that has a bow and buttons). Select the blue icon highlighted on the right (the circle with an arrow). Now press the circle on the "New Reference Outlet"-line and drag the mouse into the header file of `IMWindow`.
[image: Xcode interface builder]

That's it! Your `NSTextField` is now bound to the `IMWindow` class.

But remember: You should consider using a `NSWindowController` for this instead!

Comment: Thanks! I understand how to bind outlet but don't know about the value bindings (because I am proficient in iOS but new to OS X). Does it mean that I cannot bind to arbitrary object? Is there any limitation for the object?

Comment: Ah sorry man. I misunderstood your problem. Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14079680/1118969 ? I can see there are a lot of binding settings under `Value` if you select the second icon from right when `NSTextField` is selected.